# File uploads using AJAX / HTML 5

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, file-upload

I am trying to use AJAX and HTML5 to handle file uploads from clients computer to a folder on the server.

I am at the point where the user can browse for a file on their machine select it. Clicking the `upload` button is suppose to execute the script necessary to complete the file upload, this is where I get stuck. I am not sure how to continue coding the functionality of this file upload feature using the `upload.php` script.

My question is, assuming the folder on the server is called `docs`. How can I download the selected file by the user to the servers `docs` folder, after the user clicks on the upload button?

I appreciate any suggestions.

Many thanks in advance!

JQuery

```
    $.ajax({
        url: 'upload.php',  //server script to process data
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {  // custom xhr
            myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            if(myXhr.upload){ // check if upload property exists
                myXhr.upload.addEventListener('progress',progressHandlingFunction, false); // for handling the progress of the upload
            }
            return myXhr;
        },
        //Ajax events
        success: function(data){
            alert("OK");
            $('body').html(data);
        },
        // Form data
        data: formData,
        //Options to tell JQuery not to process data or worry about content-type
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false

    });
```

HTML

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input name="file" type="file" />
    <input type="button" value="Upload" />
    </form>
    <progress></progress>
```

Comment: This helped me a bunch when learning ajax file uploads: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/uploading-files-with-ajax/

Comment: I ran into similar problems as you not too long ago. However, I didn't really want to mess with it, so I used this extension: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload It's small, configurable and easy to set up. Just a suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this code should work for your setup. Basically it checks if you're uploading something in the first if statement. Then it checks if the file exists in the second statement. And if it doesn't, then it moves the file into an uploads folder.

```
<?php
if ($_FILES["file"]["name"] != NULL) {
  if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  else
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "uploads/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
}
?>
```

Do remember that the .php script needs the correct permissions as well as whichever folder you're putting it into. I believe `766` should do it.

You should also add an error to your ajax. Please add the following after your success

```
error : function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  console.log('An Ajax error was thrown.');
  console.log(XMLHttpRequest);
  console.log(textStatus);
  console.log(errorThrown);
},
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i'll give this a try! isn't 755 the default?

Comment: Use if(isset($_FILES["file"]["name"])) else can generate a notice

Comment: The permissions on the folder and file should be 766, I've updated my answer. Also my default for php files is `644` and `755` for folders.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please see edited JQuery. The alert message never gets executed and the success function, never gets executed and I am getting no errors, any ideas what might be the cause of this?

Comment: I've added some error checking for you in my answer. You will need to check the console to see them. Also add a line in your upload.php file to say `echo "test";` that way even if the file isn't being written, you'll know the file was sent.